# Codeigniter - Server Error - 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: codeigniter

I have uploaded my codeigniter project (which run perfectly in localhost) in live server.

My url is something like this :   `http://33.444.321.51/projects/bodyodore/`

I have a project folder in server and I put my project "bodywrapsand" under it.

When I run it load the main page perfectly.

Problem start when I select any menu link it gives me this error,
and this one is my localserver path where it run quite well.

> 404 - File or directory not found.
>   The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily 
>   unavailable.

All my class names are starting with a CAPITAL Letter and name of the controller are same as class name.

i.e. Admin.php contain class Admin extends

In config file I have:

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

My htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

I have spend 48 hours to find out solution please save me.

This is my local url:

```
http://localhost/project/buddy/
```

Comment: Make sure you have set your base url to something like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';`

Comment: Try some of these htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

1. in application/config/config.php
   set

   `$config['base_url'] = ' http://localhost/projects/bodyodore/';`
2. in your contoller include 'url' helper if not included before

   $this->load->helper('url');
3. replace your manu links to :

```html
<a href="<?php echo base_url('menu_url')?>">Menu</a>
```

Comment: Oh sorry to mention , i have done that too still the same problem I have spend two night still not find anything good. Let me mention one thing more this is my menu link.

Comment: <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/about">About Us</a></li>

Comment: try this too : <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/about">About Us</a></li>

Comment: if i modify it as under and del htaccess file it work but still get some connectivity issue etc.                                                                          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/welcome/about">About Us</a></li>  It might help to diagonase the problem i personally think it is a htaccess file issue

Comment: its better to create a new .htaccess file directly in that folder, instead of copy from somewhere else